# In python help() function shows no content

Tags: python

`help('modules')` works, but `help(object)`, e.g: `help('str')` just shows an empty line.
And in other situations like `help(function with """ """)`, there is also just one empty line.

Comment: What do you mean by "function with """ """ "? What version of Python are you talking about?

Comment: @MaJoR I think the OP means `help(name_of_some_function_with_docstring)`

Comment: Try `help(type('foo'))` to see the documentation for `str` (which is what `type('foo')` returns)

Comment: @JonathonReinhart that's what I mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per python doc

> If the argument is a string, then the string is looked up as the name of a module, function, class, method, keyword, or documentation topic, and a help page is printed on the console.

The help function print the dockstring on console for object or class or function and returns nothing i.e. you get `None`